# Font is not being changed in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

Here is a site; http://summerlove.com.au where we are using specific font-family for the words "SummerLove". But the font-family is not being changed for Firefox and IE browsers. 
I have used this css code;

```
font-family: hand_of_sean;
src: url(http://einaco.com/Hand_Of_Sean.ttf);
```

Looking for quick help from you my friends.

Kind Regards,

Mueedullah K.

Comment: I see your question has been answered, so I just want to point out that you desperately need to compress your images. From start to end on a 50 megabit FiOS connection your site took 31 seconds to download. You have 3.7 megabytes of images responsible for the majority of that, and you could easily cut that down by about 90%

Comment: I will add to that, you need to bundle and minize your CSS & JavaScript. But more than that the server really returns assets back slowly. You might want to look into using a CDN like AWS Cloudfront. Not many visitors are going to wait more than 3-4 for content to download.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Internet explorer have same-domain policies for cross-domain `@font-face` usage.

In other words, unless the domain hosting the font file is set up to pass the proper headers (see below) when a request for the font file is made, the browser will not download/use the font you specified in your CSS. If the font is hosted on the same domain, you won't have this issue.

- http://schock.net/articles/2013/07/03/hosting-web-fonts-on-a-cdn-youre-going-to-need-some-cors/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

If you check the response headers sent for the font file you mention, you'll see that it's missing the correct response header to allow the font to work cross-domain. Specifically, it's missing:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

If that were present in the response, it would work. You would have to talk to the owner of the server/website to have that changed. Alternatively, if you hosted the font on the same domain that your website is, this header would not be required.

Unrelated to your specific problem, I'd also suggest giving this a read to better understand the CSS you should be using:

- http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

And as pointed out in that article, the Font Squirrel font generator works well for getting the right CSS as well as the proper formats for the fonts:

- http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

Use the following website to generate web fonts.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sans';
    src: url('Hand_Of_Sean.eot');
    src: url('Hand_Of_Sean.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Hand_Of_Sean.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Hand_Of_Sean.ttf') format('truetype'),
  }
```

This is compatible with most of the browsers.